# How to update image using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this to display a image of the product.

```
<div class='productImageWrap' id='productImageWrapID_16'>
    <img src="abc.png" width='75' height='75' />
</div>
```

By clicking a button i want to change the image using JQuery.
I have written this code for that. But its not working.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
{
    $('#mybtn').click(function()
    {
        $("productImageWrapID_16").attr("src", "xyz.png");
    }); 
});
```

Can someone help me what is wrong in this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#productImageWrapID_16 img").attr("src", "xyz.png");
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6vbxno7n/)**

Comment: Working perfectly. Thanks. Instead of hardcoded 16 how to add product number in Jquery id. THis is not working for me 
var id =16;
$("#productImageWrapID_"+id "img").attr("src", "xyz.png");

Comment: you're missing a space after id. try this: var id =16; $("#productImageWrapID_"+id " img").attr("src", "xyz.png")

Answer (score 0):

if you use class to select use this:

```
  $('.productImageWrap img').attr('src', 'abcd.png');
```

if you use id's use this:

```
$('#productImageWrapID_16 img').attr('src', 'abcd.png');
```